# Is there any way to check a big tar.gz file's interity?

Tags: tar

A project often involves a lot of large or huge tar.gz files provided by other people. Usually around 300~400G each.

I use:
        nohup tar -tvf Data.tar.gz > test_data.log &

to check the integrity. I was wondering is there any quicker way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `gunzip -tv Data.tar.gz` if you want to check that the file hasn't been corrupted during transfer. This involves decompressing the archive, but will skip writing all that data to disk. You could do this type of check even more quickly (avoiding the decompression) if your associates are willing to provide you a separate checksum along with the archive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jjlin. Actually I tried the gunzip -tv Data.tar.gz you mentioned. But it still takes a long time.

Comment: Well, you'll really need to ask for an external checksum to be provided along with the files then, e.g. using `md5sum`, sha1sum`, etc.